# Choosing form fields by label using Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, automation, mechanize, bots

I originally wrote 800 lines to do this, site by site. However, on talking to a couple of people, it seems like my code is way longer than it needs to be.

So, I've got an idea of what you'd do in Python, with a particular Egg, but I'm working with Ruby. So, does anyone have any idea how to enter details in a form field, based on what the label for it is, rather than the id/name? Using Mechanize.

Comment: Add the code for a specific site; or at least include an example site so that it is easy to guide you in the right direction with a code example. Mechanize does have the ability to fill form fields. See http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html for some examples.

Comment: Got it now, but that's hard to do with no Mechanize experience (only Watir, which isn't useful for what I want to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your html looks like:

```
<label>Foo</label>
<input name="foo_field">
```

You can get the name of the input following a specific label:

```
name = page.at('label[text()="Foo"] ~ *[name]')[:name]
#=> "foo_field"
```

and use that to set the form value

```
form[name] = 'bar'
```